# change css onload with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, onload

It's a simple javascript command to get the classname to change when the page loads. What am I doing wrong that it isn't working? http://jsfiddle.net/wtH2Y/4/

```
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
   .away {
        margin: 30px 0 0 0 !important;
        position:fixed;
        -webkit-transition: margin 0.6s;
        -moz-transition: margin 0.6s;
        -o-transition: margin 0.6s; 
   }
   .in {
        margin:0;
        position:absolute;
   }

 </style>
 <script>
     window.onload = function pre-loader() {
        document.getElementByClassName('away').className = 'in';
     };
 </script>
</head>

<div class="away">
this should slide up when the page loads
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- Function names cannot have dashes in them. Rename your function.
- If you're using a named function, I wouldn't assign it to a property this way. Either make it anonymous or assign it like so:

  ```
  function foo() {
      ...
  }

  window.onload = foo;
  ```

  Otherwise, you won't be able to call `foo()`.
- `getElementByClassName` should be `getElementsByClassName` (notice the `s`). Also, since it'll return a collection of elements, you will need to iterate over it with a `for` loop.

Comment: good to know. I think I will just stick with getElementById. And thanks for catching the dash. smh

Answer (score 0):

Because the function is `document.getElementsByClassName` and not `document.getElementByClassName`. It returns an Array. So you need to get the first element and apply the class. Like this...

```
document.getElementsByClassName('away')[0].className = 'in';
```

To make it simple, why don't you assign an id to the div

```
<div class="away" id="mydiv">
```

and then use `document.getElementById`. Like this...

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').className = 'in';
```

It is much simpler and easy to use.

Comment: thank you! if your id is "mydiv" wouldn't you getElementById('mydiv')?

Comment: I think I did everything you said but it still doesn't seem to work. http://jsfiddle.net/wtH2Y/6/ any ideas?

Comment: I am sorry, I had provided the wrong id. Can you check my edited answer?